# How to listen to bootstrap modal close event in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-modal

I want to listen to bootstrap modal close event in react, because I have a form in modal and want to clear fields when modal close. I know how to do it in jquery like this,

```
$('#modal-form').on('hidden.bs.modal', fnClearForm);
```

But here I want to bind a function in the component.

Note: I can't use react-bootstrap.
This is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39212827/listen-for-bootstrap-modal-close-event-in-reactjs) but it doesn't address my problem.

Here is my component,

```
class MyModal extends Component {

clearForm = () => {
  -- code here --
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="modal right fade" id="add-user-modal" role="dialog">
          <div className="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div className="modal-content">
              -- form goes here --
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Here is how I open the modal,

`<a className="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#add-user-modal">..</a>`

Comment: The question is unclear. You do it the same way but instead of `fnClearForm` you'd probably use `this.handleModalClose` from your component where you _clear the form_. You start listening for that event inside `componentDidMount`.

Comment: Share your code where you open the modal and modal close handler function

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv Please show me how to do it. I have posted my component code

Comment: `$('#modal-form').modal('hide');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, Since you can't use the react package for bootstrap and only using the cdn.

I think there is no accurate way to listen the closing of the modal.
Another thing is there are few way to close a boostrap modal. (Escape Key, Clicking the background will also close the modal).

The best way I can think of on the spot is to clear the form each time it is opened.

We may not be able to listen the closing of the modal but atleast we can know when it will be opened.

Here is the sample snippet I made

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/keysl183/69z2wepo/318595/

```
class MyModal extends React.Component {
        constructor(props){
        super(props);
      this.handleOnChange = this.handleOnChange.bind(this);
      this.state= {
        testInput:""
      }
    }

    handleOnChange(e){
        this.setState({
            [e.target.name] : e.target.value
        })
    }

    ClearForm =() =>{
      this.setState({testInput:""});
    }

  render() {
      return (
          <div className="modal right fade" id="add-user-modal" role="dialog">
            <div className="modal-dialog" role="document">
              <div className="modal-content">
                   Hi <br></br>
                   Test Modal
                   <input type="text"  onChange={this.handleOnChange} name="testInput" value={this.state.testInput}  ></input>
                   <br></br>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      )
  }
}

class Hello extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
        this.MyModal = React.createRef();
  }

  render() {
    return <div>
      <MyModal ref={this.MyModal}></MyModal>
    <a onClick={()=>{this.MyModal.current.ClearForm()}}className="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#add-user-modal">SHOW MODAL</a>      
    </div>;
  }
}



ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

This will clear the input inside the modal component each time it is opened.

Also, I find it easier to create a ref instead of props when toggling a modal.
You can avoid messy props and just declare a single function inside the modal component and reuse it anywhere.

Comment: Thanks. Clearing the form when it is opened is easy to implement

Comment: No problem, as long as it helps!

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for the same thing without using `react-bootstrap`, but I REALLY wanted to know when the modal was opened and then closed (keypress, click outside or close) so I could run my `this.props.onClose` function. I finally made a sort of hack using a `MutationObserver` and attaching it to the Bootstrap modal `div`. I also included a "catch" if an `onClose` prop isn't provided.

```js
state = {
    isOpen: false
  }

  modalRef = React.createRef()

  // Check if already open and handle onClose if closing
  observer = new MutationObserver(mutation => {
    const hasShowClass = mutation[0].target.classList.contains('show')
    const { isOpen } = this.state
    
    if(hasShowClass && !isOpen) {
      this.setState({
        isOpen: true
      })
    } else if(!hasShowClass && isOpen) {
      this.props.onClose()
      this.setState({
        isOpen: false
      })
    }
  })

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.onClose &&
      this.observer.observe(this.modalRef, { 
        attributes: true, 
        attributeFilter: ['class'] 
      })
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.props.onClose && this.observer.disconnect()
  }
```

```html
<div ref={e => this.modalRef = e} className="modal fade" id={this.props.id} tabIndex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby={`user-form-modal-label`} aria-hidden="true">
</div>
```